# More elegant helper for Meteor 0.9.3 templates

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I've created a custom block helper for Meteor 0.9.3 using information from the following URL:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#new-pattern-for-defining-custom-block-helpers

It can be used within a Spacebars template like so:

```
{{#ifEqual value1="stringOrNumber_1" value2="stringOrNumber_2"}}
  <h1>The values ARE equal!</h1>
{{else}}
  <h1>The values are NOT equal!</h1>
{{/ifEqual}}
```

Here is the code:

```
<template name="ifEqual">
  {{#if isEqual value1 value2}}
    {{> UI.contentBlock}}
  {{else}}
    {{> UI.elseBlock}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

Template.ifEqual.isEqual = function (value1, value2) {
  return value1 === value2;
};
```

My question is:

Is there a possible way to make this less clunky?

I would much prefer code that can be used within a template like so:

```
{{#ifEqual "stringOrNumber_1" "stringOrNumber_2"}}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would register a global `equals` helper:

```js
Template.registerHelper('equals', function(value1, value2){
    return value1 === value2
})
```

And then use it like this:

```html
{{#if equals "abc" "abc"}}
    <p>They're equal :)</p>
{{else}}
    <p>They're not equal :(</p>
{{/if}}
```

Though, you may be interested in using the [underscore-helper](https://atmospherejs.com/pahans/underscore-helper) package instead, so you don't have to define this (and similar) helpers yourself.

Comment: Much appreciated!  Just what I was looking for.  Also: the underscore-helper package looks useful, though not for a simple string comparison function like this.